# Network traffic monitor "nettop" morphing away from expected results

Tags: shell, networking, terminal

On Mac, I open a new shell and enter `nettop`. For a split second I see chrome (as I expected) and some other things going on (had to record screen to catch them); then I'm only shown data on `UserEventAgent.11`, `configd.18` and `mDNSResponder.40`.

Is this something I should be concerned about, for one?

What do I need to do to view chrome network traffic with nettop?

Comment: Chrome uses the network sporadically most of the time (HTTP communication generated by browsers is rather small and fast), if you want to see chrome in `nettop` you should try doing a big download.  More importantly: why do you want to see chrome's network activity?  Do you want to see how much bandwidth it consumes or what kind of requests it makes?  To see actual requests you should use something like `tamper chrome` or even `wireshark` not `nettop`.

Comment: @grochmal My computer seemed busier than normal so I thought I'd check out nettop (for the first time, I might add, so basing what I expected to see on [article](http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/07/watch-network-traffic-mac-os-x-nettop/) I was reading) for anything suspicious. So, I put the terminal window next to the browser and tried to generate activity (including downloading a 1gb file) but nothing happens.

Comment: ...to be clear, that last sentence is regarding "try doing a big download", not `tamper chrome` or `wireshark`.